# How to create coach marks in android

Tags: android, overlay

I am creating coach marks in my app.I was using ShowCase view library but getting lots of issues in it.Any idea how can i create it by my own.Please help

Answer (score 1):

Fork [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) and modify it.

Comment: I have already done that but i am facing lots of issues in modifying like i want to pass the listview in the setCntMess but i am unable to

Comment: unableto change the background color and shape from circle to desired one

Comment: this is what i tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984469/how-to-set-listview-as-a-text-in-showcase-view-library